# Algorithm for winner trains?

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

This is a problem from a past exam paper:

Let there be $n$ trains `X_1,X_2 ... X_n` all which run along parallel tracks. Train $i$ starts from position `S[i] >= 0` and runs at constant speed `V[i]`. A train is said to be a winner if there exists a time interval `[t_1,t_2]` with `t_2 - t_1 < delta` where the train is ahead of all other trains. You need to output all the winner trains. Design an `O(n log n)`  algorithm for this.

As a `O(n log n)` is required, I was thinking of some divide and conquer approach, but couldn't find the appropriate combine subroutine.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting?

Comment: I can't understand why it's the software is not recognizing latex code

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow , latex is not supported on stackoverflow, only on mathoverflow

Comment: Hint: this is basically the half plane intersection problem (consider the lines `y = S[i] + V[i]*x`), which can be seen as the dual of convex hull. There are many different `n log n` algorithms for this, I'll let you google for them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you have two subproblem solved. You have already computed times where winner are changing for your subproblems:

```
0-----t0------------t1----t2-----------t3------
0--t4-----------t5------------t6---------------
```

Now to merge this: each time an *event* occurs, compare the current winner from the two lists, check their `crossing time`, if it's in the current interval add it to the event list.

The proof that this gives `O(n log n)` complexity is the same as the classic merg sort.